# sech(x) inverse for x< 0

Tags: inverse, inverse-function, hyperbolic-functions, derived-functors

I know this is probably a basic question but I spent about an hour googling it and can't find any answer actually dressing this.

I have a function $f(x) = sech(x)$ for $x<0 $

I got the log form of the inverse as

$\log{((1- \sqrt{1-X^2} /x))} $

which seems correct.

I'm just confused because the range of the inverse function doesn't seem to equal the domain of the original function

Thanks

Comment: Inverse functions' ranges are restricted so that they may still be a function...

Comment: Edited for mathjax.  Behold the power of the dollar!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw graphs

sec(x) always $>0$, $\le 1$

interchange $x,y$ axes for inverse function

$\sec^{-1}(x) $always $x>0$ as a real function. It does not exist real for $x<0$.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared it up a lot.

Comment: In my working would I say that the range of the inverse function = (-1) * domain of the original function?

Comment: And for say f(f^-1(x)) the only value that exists for it would be f^-1(x) = 0 and the other corresponding values?